# How to fetch values for every id present in array using loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have an array with following values:

```
$test = [2,8,10,12];
```

and a table `'orderdetails'` in database with `order_title` and `order_id` columns.

What I want is to fetch order_title of every order using order_id in a loop.
Can anyone help?

What I know is:

```
$test = [2,8,10,12];
foreach($test as $order_id){
$order_name = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT order_title FROM orderdetails WHERE order_id ='. $order_id);
$order_names[] = $order_name;
}
```

but this will make query run multiple times, any better solution?

UPDATE:

When I try to use IN(), values are getting inserted like this:

```
SELECT order_title FROM orderdetails WHERE order_id IN(2,8,10,12)
```

but what problem is here, query is only returning the value for first element in array that is `2`

the solution needs to get applied is `IN('2','8','10','12')`
all the values should be in a single quote, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: Besides the fact that the given query is vulnerable to SQL injection: why not use `IN()`?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried using IN() but the problem is the values needs to be in single invaded comma else it won't work.

Comment: Whatever you mean by "single invaded comma": please share your attempts such that others can see where this is going wrong

Comment: @NicoHaase updated in question.

Comment: Did you check whether `get_results` returns an array that you could iterate over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WHERE IN` :

```
$ids = implode("','", [2,8,10,12]); 
$query = "SELECT order_title FROM orderdetails WHERE order_id IN ('$ids')";
$order_name = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Query :

```
SELECT order_title FROM orderdetails WHERE order_id IN ('2','8','10','12')
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer, but problem with this solution is:

query is only returning the value for first element in array that is 2

the solution needs to get applied is IN('2','8','10','12') all the values should be in a single quote, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: @SanadQazi check my update

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
$test = [2,8,10,12];
$inclause = '';
foreach($test as $order_id){
    $inclause .= $order_id . ',';
}
$inclause = rtrim($inclause,',');
$query = 'SELECT order_title FROM orderdetails WHERE order_id IN ('. $inclause . ')';
$order_name = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer, but problem with this solution is: query is only returning the value for first element in array that is 2 the solution needs to get applied is IN('2','8','10','12') all the values should be in a single quote, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: How about this then? https://3v4l.org/ian7E